# Usage of WS2821

Tags: led, driver

I got a buck load of WS2821a, and I was wondering, can I use it for something else than driving LEDs?
TechSpec: http://www.world-semi.com/uploads/soft/140305/1-140305102109.pdf

Can it be used for:

- 0-10v
- Triggering solenoids

And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Using Transistors. Or Mosfets. The led Driving pins are basically Open Drain, so a pull up resistor and a transistor, with a low base voltage as to meet the WS2821's regulating Voltage Limit (20~40mA at ~1V, more than that can cause heat issues), would work. I've seen the same thing done on TI LED drivers. Inverted logic of course.

Answer (score 2):

The outputs of those are constant current sinks with PWM switching.  That is, you get either a constant current connection to ground, or no connection at all.

By connecting a resistor in place of the LEDs you can get an inverted PWM waveform out of the point the resistor connects to the pin.

The voltage of that waveform is dependant on the value of the resistor - it will alternate between the supply voltage (5V) and 5V - the voltage dropped by the resistor, which will depend on the current the chip is set to.  Sizing that current / resistor ration is critical to get a good waveform which drops low enough to be considered a logic LOW.

That low-powered output could then be fed into a BJT transistor or MOSFET to amplify the power.  It can also at the same time re-invert the signal to get the correct PWM signal out of it again.

And then yes, that can be used to drive anything you like.

Comment: So, If I use something like a BC527B transistor with a 1K before the base, I could fed in a MOSFET or ULN2003.